# Error: Operation not found: PutObject - during file upload to s3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

i am trying to upload a csv file from a form to my s3 bucket. everything seems to be fine.but i get the error message "Operation not found: PutObject". below is my implementation.

```
    <?php


include 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;


 $expected_filename = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

 try{


    $client = SesClient::factory(array(
            'version'   => 'latest',
            'region'    => 'eu-west-1',
            'credentials' => array(
              'key'       => 'mykey************',
              'secret'    => 'mysecret***************',
            ),
          ));


          $client->putObject([
              'Bucket' => "s3://bitb/bitb2/",
              'Key'    => $expected_filename,
              'SourceFile' => $expected_filename,
          ]);

}
catch( Exception $x )
{
    echo "Error: " . $x->getMessage() . "\n";

}
?>
```

Comment: I think you may be missing the following: `use Aws\S3\S3Client;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following directive at the beginning of your php file:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
```

Your syntax is correct but you're missing the reference to the S3 library from the SDK.